# Breaking one line of objective-c code into two

Tags: objective-c

```
NSDictionary *attributes = nil ;
*attributes = [filemanager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil] ;
```

fails with " ... error: incompatible types in assignment"

yet

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [filemanager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil] ;
```

works.

My question is how to break the one line of code that works into two lines of code that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*attributes = [filemanager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil] ;
```

Delete that '*' from the start of the line. You don't need it. Correct will be:

```
attributes = [filemanager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil] ; // no '*' before attributes
```

Comment: *attributesPointer = [filemanager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil] ;
attributesPointer = [filemanager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil] ;

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *attributes;
attributes = [filemanager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil];
```